# Backgroundimage is not working in react

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-native, reactcsstransitiongroup

I am new to react and trying to get background image with inline styling. But it's not working.

Showing error "url is not defined"

```
  render() {
    return (
        <div className="phase1" 
             style ={ { backgroundImage: url('https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/MOf9Kxxkj7GvyZlTZOnUzuYv0JAweEhlxJX6gslQvbvlhLK5_bSTK6duxY2xfbBsj43H=w300') } }>

            <input id="search" 
                   type="text" 
                   placeholder={this.state.search} 
                   onChange={this.updateSearch.bind(this)}/>
            &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;

            <Link className="button1" to="Form"> + </Link>
        </div>
       )
    }
 }
```

Comment: wrap it in quotes, you're in JS context when you put curlies in JSX so you're literally trying to call a function called `url` which doesn't exist

Comment: can you show by doing how

Answer (score 36, accepted):

CSS values are always strings. Wrap the `backgroundImage` value in quotation marks to make it a string:

```
<div className="phase1" style ={ { backgroundImage: "url('https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/MOf9Kxxkj7GvyZlTZOnUzuYv0JAweEhlxJX6gslQvbvlhLK5_bSTK6duxY2xfbBsj43H=w300')" } }>
```

Comment: @TheViralGriffin Can you open a new question for the issue you're seeing and paste the code you are using?

Comment: The issue i was facing was minor mistype. Fixed it, thanks.

Answer (score 31):

Faced a similar problem and this did the trick for me

`style={{backgroundImage: 'url(' + require('./images/sword.png') + ')'}}`

the trick was adding the `require`

Comment: Thanks. I have to note here that although I tried many things, this here worked. +1

Comment: Alternatively, ES6 `import` statement can also be used.

Answer (score 18):

In my case, i have url with space on it, so it needs to be wrapped with quotes mark ex: 'url', because i got url (imagePath) directly from server.

```
<div style={{ backgroundImage: `url('${imagePath}')` }} />
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: It saved my day! thank you! The ` ' " are so confusing 

Comment: ' - This quote inside parenthesis was very important. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

In React putting relative paths for images like this

```js
<div className="container-login100" style={{ backgroundImage: "url('./folder/images/bg-01.jpg')" }}>
```

doesn't seems to work as it is **JSX**, you need to import the image or require it

```js
import BackgroundImage from './../frontend_authentication_copied/images/bg-01.jpg'

...

styles = {
        backgroundImage: `url(${BackgroundImage})`
    }

...

<div className="container-login100" style={this.styles}>
```

Just make sure you put all the images inside the **src** folder since **relative imports** are not supported from outside the **src** folder if `create-react-app` is used.

Comment: your solution set me free from a problem that I got stuck on for 2 days!

Answer (score 5):

I've stumbled upon this thread today. I was in need to change the `backgroundImage` property dynamically, so `require` was not an option. In my ElectronJS app all I did was:

```
const imageFilePath = './some/dynamic/path/here';
const style = { backgroundImage: `url('file://${imageFilePath}')` };
```

Hope this helps somebody :)

Answer (score 4):

I was battling with this same issue this morning but i was able to fix it with below snippet.

```
<div
    className="col-md-4 col-xs-12"
    style={{
      backgroundImage: `url(${require('./path/img.png')})`,
      backgroundPosition: 'center',
      backgroundSize: 'cover',
      backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
    }}
></div>
```

Comment: I'm glad it's helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why, but for me only one way that works is like this:

```
<div style={{backgroundImage: `url(${require("./images/your_image").default})`}}></div>
```

Without the `.default` no error would occur, but the image simply would not appear in the html. I hope I helped someone ;)

Comment: Hi Saulo Felipe. The reason you needed `.default` is because `require()` imports CommonJS modules and your file/image loader (probably a webpack plugin) exposed the image as an ESM style default export. This only applies to images loaded locally, not from external URLs like in this question. it is hopefully still useful for people coming here with that problem.