# How to set the background image for a div in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm creating a react application, and I have a component that is define more or less like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: [],
      loading: true,
      error: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var _this = this;
    this.serverRequest = 
      axios
        .get("LinkToAPI")
        .then(result => {
          _this.setState({
            data: result.data,
            loading: false,
            error: null
          });
        })
        .catch(err => {
          _this.setState({
            loading: false,
            error: err
          });
        });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.serverRequest.abort();
  }

  renderLoading() {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }

  renderError() {
    return (
      <div>
        Something when wrong: {this.state.error.message}
      </div>
    );
  }

  renderData() {
    const { error, data} = this.state;

    if (error) {
      return this.renderError();
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {data.map(d=> {
          if (d.imageUrl) {
            <div className="dataDiv" style="background: url('{d.imageUrl}')" key={d.Id}>{d.name}</div>
          } else {
            <div className="dataDiv" style="background: url('LinkToSomeImage')" key={d.Id}>{d.name}</div>
          }
        }
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.props.loading ? this.renderLoading() : this.renderData()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

It basically gets the JSON data from the API, and using it renders some divs with the data inside the JSON. I'm applying to the divs containing the data `dataDiv` class, which is define inside my `App.css` file. Additionally, I want to set a background image for the div. What exactly I want to do is that if the data entry includes a field named `imageUrl` I want to use that url as a url to the background image, otherwise, if it is null or empty, I want to use a default url that I found from the internet. What is a proper way to handle this in React? The code segment above doesn't seem to work, especially the if-else statement inside the `renderData` function. How can I fix this code, or is there any way to handle this more gracefully, probably maybe inside the CSS?

Comment: you can set a classname which is mapped to a specific `background-url`, or set `{background-url: 'url'}` on the element directly

Comment: @DanielLizik But, I'm getting the url basically from the API. How can I do this?

Comment: `<div style={{backgroundUrl: this.state.url}}>`

Comment: @DanielLizik Okay thanks. And how do you propose to handle the if-else part in the return statement, as it is the main one giving me error.

Comment: return a different component without style

Comment: @DanielLizik If you can write an answer with a code segment, I can accept.

Comment: Check out the solution proposed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38794106/backgroundimage-is-not-working-in-react/47237937#47237937

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do like this
Please make sure to check `backgroundUrl` equal to your desired CSS.

```html
{data.map(d => {
  let backgroundUrl = "LinkToSomeImage";
  if (d.imageUrl) {
    backgroundUrl = d.imageUrl;
  } 
  
  return (
    <div className="dataDiv" style={{backgroundImage: `url(${backgroundUrl})`}} key={d.Id}>{d.name}</div>
  )
})}
```

**EDIT**

A full function would be:

```html
renderData() {
  const { error, data} = this.state;

  if (error) {
    return this.renderError();
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {data.map(d => {
        let backgroundUrl = "LinkToSomeImage";
        if (d.imageUrl) {
          backgroundUrl = d.imageUrl;
        } 

        return (
          <div className="dataDiv" style={{backgroundImage: `url(${backgroundUrl})`}} key={d.Id}>{d.name}</div>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: This kind of broke my code. I don't get any errors, but I get nothing displayed too. Can you write the whole function and not just the code snipped?

Comment: Same again, this is how my function looks: https://jsfiddle.net/v5eqL44c/

Comment: Sorry, it should be `backgroundImage`. So `style={{backgroundImage: ...}}`

Comment: Again same. Did you check my jsfiddle? Can the problem be that we are trying to return inside the map?

Comment: Update for full function. You did not have `return` in `renderData`

Answer (score 0):

```
          <Box
            onClick={() => {
              history.push({
                pathname: `/p/c/${data.ProductName.replace(/\//g, "~")}/1`
              });
            }}
            css={{
              backgroundImage:`url(${data.imageUrl||"/default-placeholder.png"})`,
              backgroundPosition: 'center',
              backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat'
            }}
          >
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.