# Inline background-image in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to set a background image via inline styles in React.

After looking through a few posts [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38794106/backgroundimage-is-not-working-in-react)'s solution worked for me:

```
<div className="phase1" style ={ { backgroundImage: "url('https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/MOf9Kxxkj7GvyZlTZOnUzuYv0JAweEhlxJX6gslQvbvlhLK5_bSTK6duxY2xfbBsj43H=w300')" } }>
```

I pasted that directly into my component without changing the link just to test it, and it worked. But now that I am trying to reference an image from my `/src` folder it isn't working.

```
<div className='background-image' style ={ { backgroundImage: "url('../../../../images/products/cards/main.jpg')" } }>asdfasdfasdfasdf</div>
```

Nothing shows up and I am not getting any error or warning.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39195687/setting-a-backgroundimage-with-react-inline-styles

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I figured it out, you can't just put a link straight into url. You need to `require` it first.

```
var bg=require('../../../../images/products/cards/main.jpg')
return (      
  <div className="ProductItem">

      {/* Background Image */}
      <div className='background-image' style ={ { backgroundImage: "url("+bg+")" } }></div>
```

Comment: That's not necessary, you just need to ensure that the image you're trying to load is in a public path (If you access that path with your browser the image is visible)

Comment: @Miguel sometimes the image you need to load is not in a publica path and you can't ensure it will be

Answer (score 6):

## Hello

Everybody after some Research I found a better solution for this question like this

```
import BannerBgImg1 from "../../assets/static/img/banner/banner_bg_img_1.jpg";

<div className="bannerInnerItem" style={{backgroundImage: `url(${BannerBgImg1})` }}>
```

is the best way to use this

Comment: it should be background instead of backgroundImage

Answer (score 1):

```
 const Images = [
    require('./greenbanner.jpg'),
    require('./greengrass.jpeg'),
    require('./opengreen.jpg')   ];
```

This is for an  array of images that should be required 
we need to require them when they cannot be loaded

Answer (score 1):

I hope Background Img is very common. So please try to use it. It is very easy to use. At first you should import img and then easily use it in your jxs file.

```
import InnerBgImg from "../../assets/static/img/banner/inner_banner_bg_static.jpg";
return (
    <div className="inner_banner" style={{ backgroundImage: "url(" + InnerBgImg +")" }}>
```